# PHP Cart Object for Expresso:Store

Tags: expresso-store, categories, php, checkout

Is there a cart object for Expresso:Store? Something like "$this->EE->cartObject" where I can access the items that is in the cart? The purpose of this is to find out which category the item is in and if it is in a category that does not ship to a country it will display a warning message and blank out the 'confirm purchase' button.

Regards,
Rin

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access it like this:

```
ee()->store_cart->contents();
```

There are also many [extension hooks](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html) you can use if you want to validate the cart when it is updated.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to access this via the template level, is it only for development of plugins?

Comment: The cart library needs to be loaded, and from memory in templates the EE super object is accessible directly. Try `ee()->store_cart->contents()` as I just put above (assuming you are using EE 2.6+).