# Expresso Store get cart items in PHP

Tags: expresso-store, php, expresso

EE: 6.3.4

I am aware that Expresso Store is discontinued. I would like to be able to get the contents of the user's current cart in PHP. The answer [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12632/php-cart-object-for-expressostore) does not work (`ee()->store_cart->contents()`).

I asked the same question for a different cart addon [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/42367/cartthrob-cart-items-info-in-php). If there is a similar solution, I would really appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use `ee()->store->orders->get_cart()->toTagArray()`

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: not that I know of; I had to look in the code I had on hand to find that call tbh